# Firebase Hosting - getting Insecure Connection warning with custom domain redirection

Tags: https, firebase-hosting

I have a custom domain name redirected to a **Firebase Hosting** site, which worked fine for a month or two but now am getting an **Insecure Connection** warning when I visit the domain -

> (domain name) uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is only valid for the following names: firebaseapp.com, *.firebaseapp.com
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN

The `https://(project name).firebaseapp.com` link works okay.

The Firebase Console is showing **Needs Setup** for the domain status, though it seems to be set up properly with the two A records, the TXT record, and a URL Redirect record, and the domain is listed as Verified.

The only thing that might have changed was in starting to set up **Google G Suite**, which required adding another TXT record for domain verification - I think after that the site started showing the security warning. I tried removing the TXT records and readding them but it didn't help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Firebase Support is the only people that can really do anything. https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: @abraham okay - I wrote to them also

Comment: So google sends people to stackoverflow for questions but it's closed as off-topic? https://firebase.google.com/support/
Sorry, I'm confused. Where does one for firebase support then?

Comment: @EnricRibas hah, yes - there seem to be 68k questions tagged 'firebase' on here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase

Comment: @BrianBurns did you find the solution? I got into the same problem.

Comment: @AkPasaf yeah, just wrote an answer -

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this here in the future (as of 2022), it can take up to 24 hours for setup to complete.

"Domain changes are propagating. This may take up to 24 hours. Please check back later."

You should see a "Pending" status next to the domain name when you view the hosting module in the Firebase console.

Answer (score 1):

"*Extra changes can take more time for propagation or provisioning of the SSL certificate.*" [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/custom-domain#verify-domain-ownership) says.

So you could try after 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote to Firebase support and they noticed that I had the wrong A records in place - my domain settings (with Namecheap) had the correct A records, but I also had a URL redirect record, which is apparently bad. Try https://www.ultratools.com/tools/dnsLookupResult to make sure you have the right values.